# Scala: How to group by a timestamp an Iterable[T] into an Iterable [T]

Tags: scala, group-by, iterator

I would like to write code that would group a line iterator inputs: `Iterator[InputRow]` by timestamp an unique items (by `unit` and `eventName`), i.e. `eventTime` should be the latest timestamp in the new `Iterator[T]` list where `InputRow` is defined as

```
case class InputRow(unit:Int, eventName: String, eventTime:java.sql.Timestamp, value: Int)
```

Example data before grouping:

```
+-----------------------+----+---------+-----+
|eventTime              |unit|eventName|value|
+-----------------------+----+---------+-----+
|2018-06-02 16:05:11    |2   |B        |1    |
|2018-06-02 16:05:12    |1   |A        |2    |
|2018-06-02 16:05:13    |2   |A        |2    |
|2018-06-02 16:05:14    |1   |A        |3    |
|2018-06-02 16:05:15    |2   |A        |3    |
```

After:

```
+-----------------------+----+---------+-----+
|eventTime              |unit|eventName|value|
+-----------------------+----+---------+-----+
|2018-06-02 16:05:11    |2   |B        |1    |
|2018-06-02 16:05:14    |1   |A        |3    |
|2018-06-02 16:05:15    |2   |A        |3    |
```

What is a good approach to writing the above code in Scala?

Comment: Very nice question. Well-posed and nicely scoped. In future, it might be nice to add a copy-and-pasteable bit of code to generate your input data structure, though.

Comment: @erip thanks for editing my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news: your question already contains the verbs that correspond to the functional calls to be used in the code: group by, sort by (latest timestamp).

To sort `InputRow` by latest timestamp, we'll need an implicit ordering:

```
implicit val rowSortByTimestamp: Ordering[InputRow] = 
    (r1: InputRow, r2: InputRow) => r1.eventTime.compareTo(r2.eventTime)
// or shorter:
// implicit val rowSortByTimestamp: Ordering[InputRow] = 
//   _.eventTime compareTo _.eventTime
```

And now, having

```
val input: Iterator[InputRow] = // input data
```

Let's group them by (unit, eventName)

```
val result = input.toSeq.groupBy(row => (row.unit, row.eventName))
```

then extract the one with the latest timestamp

```
  .map { case (gr, rows) => rows.sorted.last }
```

and sort from ealiest to latest

```
  .toSeq.sorted
```

The result is

```
InputRow(2,B,2018-06-02 16:05:11.0,1)
InputRow(1,A,2018-06-02 16:05:14.0,3)
InputRow(2,A,2018-06-02 16:05:15.0,3)
```

Comment: `.sorted.last` can by `.maxBy(_.eventTime)`. :)

Comment: @antot do you have an idea why getting errors for r1 and r2: `Error: missing parameter type
    implicit val rowSortByTimestamp: Ordering[InputRow] = (r1, r2) => r1.eventTime.compareTo(r2.eventTime)`

Comment: @Philip you can try it as `(r1: InputRow, r2: InputRow) => ...`, but still it works without explicit types in my test.

Comment: @erip `.maxBy(_.eventTime)` requires implicit `Ordering` for `Timestamp`...

Comment: @Antot Yes, I understand that. You define an `implicit Ordering` for `InputRow`, so you might as well make your implicit strictly more general. It'll buy you `O(log n)` time.

Comment: @erip, I agree, thanks for your comments, it can improve the solution if there are huge data to process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `struct` *built-in function* to combine `eventTime` and `value` column as `struct` so that `max` by `eventTime` (latest) can be taken when *groupBy* `unit` and `eventName` and *aggregating*, which should give you your desired output

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("struct", struct("eventTime", "value"))
    .groupBy("unit", "eventName")
    .agg(max("struct").as("struct"))
    .select(col("struct.eventTime"), col("unit"), col("eventName"), col("struct.value"))
```

as

```
+-------------------+----+---------+-----+
|eventTime          |unit|eventName|value|
+-------------------+----+---------+-----+
|2018-06-02 16:05:14|1   |A        |3    |
|2018-06-02 16:05:11|2   |B        |1    |
|2018-06-02 16:05:15|2   |A        |3    |
+-------------------+----+---------+-----+
```

Comment: But... there is not a single word about Spark in the question?!

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, you were right. I'm using Spark ;) But I need implement internal in UDF function for stateful, so I couldn't use data frame.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Philip its your choice whether you prefer dataframe/dataset or not. But what I know is that spark team has been working on dataset and dataframes to improve on rdds and you can perform any operations on dataframe/dataset that you can perform on rdds with more efficient and optimized form. And you don;t have always to depend on udf functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that with a `foldLeft` and a `map`:

```
val grouped: Map[(Int, String), InputRow] = 
  rows
    .foldLeft(Map.empty[(Int, String), Seq[InputRow]])({ case (acc, row) =>
     val key = (row.unit, row.eventName)
     // Get from the accumulator the Seq that already exists or Nil if
     // this key has never been seen before
     val value = acc.getOrElse(key, Nil)
     // Update the accumulator
     acc + (key -> (value :+ row))
  })
  // Get the last element from the list of rows when grouped by unit and event.
  .map({case (k, v) => k -> v.last})
```

This assumes that the `eventTime`s are already stored in sorted order. If this is not a safe assumption, you can define an `implicit Ordering` for `java.sql.Timestamp` and replace `v.last` with `v.maxBy(_.eventTime)`.

See [here](https://ideone.com/nLFDTu).

### Edit

Or use `.groupBy(row => (row.unit, row.eventName))` instead of the `foldLeft`:

```
implicit val ordering: Ordering[Timestamp] = _ compareTo _
val grouped = rows.groupBy(row => (row.unit, row.eventName))
                  .values
                  .map(_.maxBy(_.eventTime))
```